# XMLEventReader: avoid ParseError when at end of file

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to implement an XMLReader that reads from a socket and returns full XML documents:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Stack;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

public class MyXmlReader {
  private final XMLInputFactory infactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
  private final InputStream inStream;

  public MyXmlReader(final InputStream inStream){
    this.inStream= inStream;
  }

  private String readUntilEndOfXml() throws XMLStreamException{
    final XMLEventReader eventReader= infactory.createXMLEventReader(inStream);

    final StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    final Stack<String> openTags= new Stack<String>();
    boolean endOfXml= false;
    while (eventReader.hasNext() && !endOfXml){
      final XMLEvent nextEvent= eventReader.nextEvent();
      sb.append(nextEvent.toString());
      if (nextEvent.isStartElement()){
        openTags.add(nextEvent.toString());
      }else if (nextEvent.isEndElement()){
        openTags.pop();
        if (openTags.isEmpty()){
          endOfXml= true;
        }
      }
    }

    eventReader.close();
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final File f= new File("/tmp/double.xml");
    final MyXmlReader r= new MyXmlReader(new FileInputStream(f));

    String xml;
    while((xml= r.readUntilEndOfXml()) != null){
      System.out.println("Got an XML");
    }
  }
}
```

However, I get the following Exception if the end of the file is reached (or the socket is closed, when reading from a socket):

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:594)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.nextEvent(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:85)
    at com.siemens.bfr2.plato.MyXmlReader.readUntilEndOfXml(MyXmlReader.java:40)
    at com.siemens.bfr2.plato.MyXmlReader.main(MyXmlReader.java:125)
```

I was expecting that the check for `eventReader.hasNext()` would suffice. Why is `eventReader.hasNext()` still returning `true`, when actually there is no more data?

Comment: What is your `inStream`?

Comment: @VimalBera It seems to be independend of the input stream It happened with a File input stream as well with an input stream from a socket. However, I have edited my code to show an example with a `FileInputStream`.